# Why can't I use Googlemail as my mail relay server?

Tags: postfix, gmail

I recently installed Postfix on my virtual machine. I'm running Fedora 15 on VirtualBox.

I've found several tutorials for having emails created on Postfix get routed through my gmail account (so my emails don't get dropped to people's spam folders). My problem with these tutorials is that none of them specifically address Fedora 15.

The tutorials that I've found are:

1. http://www.postfix.org/SOHO_README.html
2. http://rs20.mine.nu/w/2011/07/gmail-as-relay-host-in-postfix/

But, I'm still not able to receive emails in my inbox. They still get dropped into my spam folder.

It would be ideal for me to have the emails sent through my GMail account. My roommates and I don't have our own ISP. Our neighbors have generously allowed to use their internet connection. Also, since I'm installing on Postfix on my laptop, I'm a little hesitant to bother configuring Postfix to my neighbors ISP (I got the impression that was an option from Tutorial #1).

So, is Tutorial #2 completely bogus? Could I be making a mistake? Are there other tutorials that can address this?

Answer (score 2):

The systems are doing exactly what they are designed to do based upon your description. The arrangement that you described is a totally untrusted configuration, if not outright illegal based upon your neighbor's ISP AUP and/or laws governing "thief of services" that may exist covering where you live.

Your best bet is to subscribe to your own legitimate ISP account which in most cases will include some appropriately functioning SMTP relay option or business class ISP services where the IP is not listed on the blacklists nor limited in any way by the ISP.

Comment: I'm not stealing their internet. I have their explicitly stated permission to use their connection.

Comment: Depending on the laws and their ISP AUP, they may not necessarily have the right to reassign their services to anyone else. Your described configuration is not that different from an outright hijack - thus the systems are doing their job.

Comment: I'll have to check with them tomorrow and see what they know about their ISP's AUP. I hadn't realized it would be an issue and they, presumably, didn't either because I had explained to them that I was working on this while we were having one of our smoke breaks this afternoon. 

I'm still not clear on how this is no different than an outright hijack (and feel free to not explain this) because it doesn't seem all that different than purchasing my own ISP acount (which for various reasons isn't possible right now) and sharing that connection with my roommates.

Comment: Ok, try sharing your cable service with your housing complex/neighborhood and see how the cable company and/or law enforcement responds.